# Understanding Django/REST/JS code functionality

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have the following code in my website:

```
<tr onclick="editUsers(29)" data-id="29">
```

editUsers:

```
function editUsers(id) {
  loadUsers(false, id, showUsers, true);
}
```

loadUsers:

```
  function loadUsers(insert, id, func_call, html_form) {
  var data = insert ? {insert: true} : {}
  if (html_form)
    data.html_form = true;
    $.ajax({
             type: 'GET',
             url:  '/rest/user/' + id + '/',
             data: data
           })
      .done(function (data) {
        func_call(data, insert, id);
      })
      .fail(function () {
      });
}
```

When I click on the row, it should open an interface to edit the selected row/user, but nothing happens. I do get a reply in the console, which looks like it should work, but it doesn't. Can someone explain why it doesn't work?
The reply in question:`"GET /rest/user/29/?html_form=true HTTP/1.1" 200 3170`

I have the same functionality elsewhere in my code, which adds a new user:

```
function addUsers() {
  loadUsers(true, 0, showUsers, true);
}
<div class="btn btn-primary pull-right" onclick="addUsers()">Add User</div>
```

The above doesn't work, editing the user doesn't either.

EDIT: showUsers function

```
function showUsers(data, insert, id) {
  var form = $(data),
      $a= form.find('select[name="a"]'),
      $b= form.find('select[name="b"]');
  $a.on("change", function (e) { $b.val($a.val()).trigger('change'); });
  var p    = {
    type:     BootstrapDialog.TYPE_PRIMARY,
    title:    '{% trans "Add User" %}',
    message:  form,
    closable: true,
    cssClass: 'usersDialog',
    buttons:  [
      {
        label:  gettext('Cancel'),
        hotkey: 27,
        action: function (dlg) { dlg.close(); }
      },
      {
        label:    gettext('Save'),
        cssClass: 'btn-primary',
        action:   function (dlg) {
          var data       = form.find('#users-form').serializeForm();
          dlg.close();

          var storeData = function storeData(data) {
            data.html_form = true;
            $.ajax({
                     type:     data.id == '' ? 'POST' : 'PUT',
                     url:      '/rest/user/' + (data.id == '' ? '' : data.id + '/'),
                     data:     data,
                     dataType: 'json',
                     headers:  {'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}'}
                   })
              .done(function (res) {
                //self.updDeviceFields(res);
                if (conflictDialogs.length > 0)
                  storeData(conflictDialogs.pop());
                else
                  location.reload();
                //$.dreamAlert({type: 'success', message: gettext('Changes saved'), position: 'right'});
              }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              console.log([jqXHR.status, jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown]);
              if (jqXHR.status == 400) {
                p.message = $(jqXHR.responseText);
                form      = p.message;
                currentForm = form;
                currentDialog = BootstrapDialog.show(p);
              }
              else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                currentDialog = BootstrapDialog.show(p);
              }
              //$.dreamAlert({type: 'error', message: gettext('Error saving changes'), position: 'right'});
            });
          }
          storeData(data);
        }
      }
    ]
  }
  if (conflictDialogs.length > 0) {
    p.animate = false;
    p.cssClass += ' flip';
  }
  currentDialog = BootstrapDialog.show(p);
  currentForm = form;
}
```

Comment: And what is `showUsers`?

Comment: Put a parameter on .fail() and let's see what it returns to understand the error.

Comment: @DaniloAkamine I added `function (jqXHR, textStatus, error)` and `console.log("Post error: " + error);` in the .fail() part, but I get nothing in the console, just the same response as above.

Comment: But this code doesn't make any sense at all. You have a function `showUsers` which you pass in as a callback to fire when the ajax response in loadUsers completes. But showUsers doesn't do anything at all to show users, instead it wants to try to set up listeners on a form. So what, exactly, are you expecting to happen, and why would you think this would work?

Comment: I was expecting that I would get a form to edit the settings of an user, when I click on him in the list. All it gives me in the console is a GET request, but nothing happens. A form opens, if I paste the HTML part of the GET request. I thought it would work, but I'm not too experienced as to why it doesn't work. What needs to be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out when I dug deep into the code. Turns out I had a syntax error which I completely missed when writting the code.

When copy pasting the code from a different page, I copied the variable name as well. My HTML looked like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">{% render_field foo_form.one bar_style %}</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">{% render_field foo_form.two bar_style %}</div>
</div>
```

When it should have looked like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">{% render_field foo_form.one foo_style %}</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">{% render_field foo_form.two foo_style %}</div>
</div>
```

I didn't see the style of importance, since it was defined as an empty list, so I completely missed the error.