# Django REST not rendering form correctly

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have the following code, that should render a list of FooBars. I have two problems: The first is, when I uncomment the state, foo and bar objects, the list renders them with actual data from the database (they're choice fields), but when I leave them commented, it just displays the choice integer.

The second problem is, that when I then navigate to `rest/foo/1/?html_form=true` and look at the HTML form, it only renders the `state`, `foo` and `bar` fields, if I leave them commented. I want to leave them uncommented, so that the user can view the actual data, however that disables me or the user from editing those fields.

What am I doing wrong?

**rest.py**

```
class FooBarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)
    #state = serializers.SerializerMethodField(label=_('State'))
    #foo = serializers.SerializerMethodField(label=_('Foo'))
    #bar = serializers.SerializerMethodField(label=_('Bar'))

    def get_state(self, obj):
        return obj.get_state_display()

    def get_foo(self, obj):
        return obj.get_foo_display()

    def get_bar(self, obj):
        return obj.get_bar_display()

    class Meta:
        model = FooBar
        fields = ('id', 'state', 'foo', 'bar', 'bool1', 'bool2', 'bool3')

class FooBarViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = FooBarSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, IsAdminUser)
    queryset = FooBar.objects.all()

    def render_form(self, request, serializer, status):
        from django.shortcuts import render
        return render(request, 'foo/foobar_item.html', {
            'intent_form': serializer,
            'intent_style': {},
        }, status=status)

router.register(r'rest/foo', FooBarViewSet, 'foobaritem')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question can be referred to the answer in [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56465873/understanding-django-rest-js-code-functionality). Instead of `intent_style` in the HTML file, I had written `bar_stlye`, so it didn't work properly.